make google chrome show bookmarks on overriden new tab
I want to make chrome open my html in a new tab and show bookmarks just like in a normal new chrome tab
I made an extensetion that contains this
{
  "name": "My custom new tab page",
  "description": "Overrides the new tab page",
  "version": "0.1",
  "incognito": "split",
  "chrome_url_overrides": {
    "newtab": "new-tab.html"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}

how can I show bookmarks on top of browser only on this page?
